# "Undefined control sequence." when using animate package (animateinline)

Tags: animate

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,final]{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx,loop,palindrome,autoplay]{animate}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}{1}
        \setatomsep{3em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
        \newframe
        \setatomsep{2.5em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
        \newframe
        \setatomsep{2em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
        \newframe
        \setatomsep{1.5em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
        \newframe
        \setatomsep{1em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this I get the following warning + nothing on the page.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \origin:pbs@obj16 used!
l.20 \end{animateinline}
```

The same goes with "\newframe". My suspicion is that its the pdfbase.sty that is throwing the error.

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx,11pt,a4paper,fleqn,final]{article}
\usepackage[loop,palindrome,autoplay]{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}{1}
        a
        \newframe
        b
        \newframe
        c
        \newframe
        d
        \newframe
        e
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This render: [image: animate render]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver `dvipdfmx` cannot be auto-detected and must be passed as an option to all packages which contain `dvipdfmx`-specific code. In the code example, these are `animate` and `ocgx2` (not used, currently). (Another popular package is `hyperref`.)

Therefore, driver options are usually set globally with the documentclass as in:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx,11pt,a4paper,fleqn,final]{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usepackage[loop,palindrome,autoplay]{animate}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}{1}
        \setatomsep{3em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
        \newframe
        \setatomsep{2.5em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
        \newframe
        \setatomsep{2em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
        \newframe
        \setatomsep{1.5em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
        \newframe
        \setatomsep{1em}\chemfig{O=C=O}
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Note that the animation widget size is defined by the first frame's dimensions and that the frames to follow are stretched or squeezed to fit into this widget. Consider putting all frames into a box with the *same* pre-defined width together with a `\strut` to also extend the box vertically, e. g.

```
\makebox[8em][c]{\strut\setatomsep{3em}\chemfig{O=C=O}}
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution but I cannot get it to work (except that I get SOMETHING rendered upon compilation). I have made the example even more slimmed down but cannot get the simple animation to work anyway... (added more info to the question).

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using? A-Reader, Foxit, PDF-XChange are supported (because animations rely on JavaScript) .

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2015.020.20042

Comment: Works perfectly here, using an older Acrobat Reader. Do you process the code with `latex` and `dvipdfmx` and is your TeX installation up-to-date?

Comment: I use BaKoMa and I guess that is what I do (latex + dvipdfmx). I have a hard time figuring out how to see this within the editor of BaKoMa.

Comment: I don't know the status of LaTeX packages in BaKoMa, and whether  BaKoMa opens the PDF in Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @JimmyWestberg : Could you switch to TeXLive? It is open-source and has a package manager. You could also try an online LaTeX editor such as overleaf.com, download the PDF and open it in A-Reader.

Comment: Overleaf worked just great. I guess it's BaKoMa that is not working properly. Thanks!

Comment: I have discussed it with the BaKoMa developer and the problem is caused by the recently updated animate package which is not (at the moment) compatible with BaKoMa. I will revert back to older animate version for now.

Comment: I had a look into BaKoMa's directory of package documentation files (http://bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex). Everything is horribly old, mostly from 2010. Cannot imagine to spend money on getting such an outdated TeX system. Are you really forced to use BaKoMa? Why not using TeXLive and LyX (quasi-wysiwyg)?

Comment: I really like the WYSIWYG of BaKoMa but I have to add some packages manually. I am not forced but I really got to learn alot of Latex thanks to the super fast render. I guess I could switch to TexLive but it did not work as fluent as I wished when I tried yesterday.

Comment: I don't know how tightly BaKoMa is interleaved with the TeX system it comes with. Maybe it is possible to configure the BaKoMa editor to use TeXLive as its TeX backend? This would be a nice option.